# how to fix PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents without calling PagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android

I have created a `recycleview` in which i implemented an `image slider`. The `image slider` may have different list size which causes the error

> PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents without calling

PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged!

This is how i have been calling the image slider adapter inside the `recycleview adapter`

```
SlidingImageDealsAdapter slidingImageDealsAdapter=   new SlidingImageDealsAdapter(context, myimagesList);
                    holder.mPager.setAdapter(slidingImageDealsAdapter);
```

so i am looking for a way to implement a `recycleview with an image slider where the list of item used for the adapter of the image slider may have different size

Comment: After You change content in adapter, you must call notify. Otherwise adapter will work on old data.

Comment: if i call notify it will change the other image slider content

Comment: So Your logic in code is wrong. Please provide more details in Your project.

Comment: You displayed code where adapter is being set. But where is the part of code where You change data in adapter?

Comment: juste before calling the adapter, in each row of the recyle view i change the content of myimagesList

Comment: Could You share the project?

Answer (score -1):

As the way i understood your question , try this it will helps you `recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);`